# Java Jacob COM Bridge: cyclic dispatch.call(...) gets slower and slower on each call

Tags: java, performance, dispatch, jacob

I have a problem using the method: Dispatch.call(….).
This Method is called cyclic (every second). The problem is that each call lasts longer. So after about 100 cycles the duration has doubled.

Here are some details:
I am using Jacob Com Bridge in Java to control PSS Sincal 11.0.
The method is highlighted and the whole class is in the attachment.
It also shows how I found out that the Dispatch.call(…) lasts longer and longer…

```
    public boolean start_simulation() {
```

//long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

```
            Dispatch.call(this.siSimulation, "Start", this.Calculation_method);
```

//System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);

```
            int stat_id = Dispatch.get(this.siSimulation, "StatusID").getInt();

            if (stat_id != SincalController.ID_SimulationOK) {
                    return false;
            } else {
                    return true;
            }
    }
```

I have nothing found on your website and google where a similar problem occurred. So I would be grateful if you could help me!

Thanking you in advance, best regards, Andreas.

Comment: In every second you start a new simulation?

Comment: Yes. PSS Sincal is an Load Flow Calculation program. To see the voltage values at each point in an electical grid I simulate it every second with new load values. The output is saved in another class, so the at each sim step the database of the sincal program is rewritten!  I recognized by looking at the task manager that the SimulationServer is growing about 1MB everey 50-100 sim steps.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is not a problem of PSS Sincal, because a colleague of mine uses the same Sincal Automation as I in MATLAB. There it works!!